# How to remove gpiod error in SWupdate Installations

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, embedded-linux, swupdate

I am currently installing `swupdate` but
getting an error while running `make command` in swupdate file.

I followed the following steps to first install it -

1. `sudo apt-get install libgpiod-dev`
2. Ran make command in the swupdate file

Even after installing gpiod following error was shown

error

````
*too many arguments to function ```gpio_line_request_output``*`
````

Is there a way I can make changes in `menuconfig` ?

[image]

Comment: Nobody knows what `swupdate` is and where its source code located...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libgpiod has rather changed its API and the signature of that function. To fix this, you have to set (or unset, it depends on the installed libgpiod) CONFIG_UCFW_OLD_LIBGPIOD in SWUpdate configuration.